# Phpcs svg escape function wordpress

Tags: wordpress, phpcs

i'll try to be quick in my question ! 
My problem is that i use the svg icons system as the tweentyseventeen default theme ! but when i use echo get_svg() function. phpcs give me a warning that all output need to be escaped with escaping function ?
any help how to acheive that with my svgs ?

Answer (score 2):

you can escape an svg via wp_kses like so:

```php
    $string = 'your svg code ala <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="..."><path d="..."/></svg>'
    echo wp_kses($string, [
      'svg' => [
        'xmlns' => [], 
        'width' => [], 
        'height'=> [], 
        'viewbox' => [] //lowercase not camelcase!
      ], 
      'path' => [
        'd' => []
      ]
    ]);
```

basically you need to add your allowed HTML elements like svg, path, {...} as an array and inside each you need to pass the allowed attributes (also as arrays). in case of `svg` this could be xmlns, width, height, {...} and in case of `path` this could be d, style, {...}. maybe you also need to add `circle` or whatever other svg elements, that come to mind..

Comment: Your note about lowercase finally moved me forward after hours of searching. Thanks. I have huge SVG files and so many attributes were being stripped and I couldn't figure out why. `viewbox`, `preserveaspectratio`, `linearGradient`, `gradientTransform`, `spreadMethod`, `radialGradient`, `gradientUnits`, `gradientTransform` etc

Answer (score 1):

You can either escape using functions like [`wp_kses_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_post/) or simillar that won't destroy the markup of the SVG code. But if you don't actually want to escape anything (despite is not recommended), you can use the [whitelisting flags](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards/wiki/Whitelisting-code-which-flags-errors).

Example of use on your case:

```php
echo get_svg(); // WPCS: XSS Ok.
```

Comment: First , thanks a lot for your answer ! i really tried every wp_kses functions for escaping svg output but nothing works for me :(